# xsi:type, is blocked or not validly derived from the type definition of the element declaration

Tags: magento2, module

I got this error :

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):  
Element 'title', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': 
The type definition 'string', specified by xsi:type, is blocked or not validly derived from the type definition of the element declaration.
```

When trying to enable my module